# I am receiving Tensorflow error “ValueError: None values not supported.” while trying to populate tf dataset. Can somebody help me?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have stored my data in a rank 2 (N x 3) tensor, and I am trying to gather specific rows of this tensor to yield the data of a single example to be fed into a Keras training loop. Basically, the idea is simply as follows: Indices Ib (say, 100) and Ie (say, 207) unique for each example specify that my input data is a 300 x 3 tensor from rows 76, 77, 78, ..., 100, 105, 110, 115, ... 205, 207, 208, 209, ... (until a total of 300 indices per example) of the data tensor. Notice the stride of 5 between Ib and Ie. While the attached code works just fine when fetching data manually (as shown in the code example), something happens when Tensorflow tries to do the same later on. Also, I know that the code below works if I just picked a fixed number of rows before and after Ib. It seems that the line `updates = tf.range(start=Ib, limit=Ie, delta=5, dtype=tf.int32)` doesn't quite yield any reasonable output when called with symbolic tensors Ib, Ie (?), thus causing the code to break up on the next line. I am using Python 3.7 / Tensorflow 2.3.0, and the attached code produces output

```
2020-08-18 10:25:51.384252: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-08-18 10:25:51.394210: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7ff732d46110 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-08-18 10:25:51.394226: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version

trainINDX =   0, X.shape = [ 300, 3 ]
trainINDX =   1, X.shape = [ 300, 3 ]
trainINDX =   2, X.shape = [ 300, 3 ]
trainINDX =   3, X.shape = [ 300, 3 ]
trainINDX =   4, X.shape = [ 300, 3 ]
trainINDX =   5, X.shape = [ 300, 3 ]
trainINDX =   6, X.shape = [ 300, 3 ]
trainINDX =   7, X.shape = [ 300, 3 ]
trainINDX =   8, X.shape = [ 300, 3 ]
trainINDX =   9, X.shape = [ 300, 3 ]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testData.py", line 93, in <module>
    main( )
  File "testData.py", line 80, in main
    trainData = trainData.map(fetchData, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
  File "/Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1702, in map
    preserve_cardinality=True)
  File "/Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 4084, in __init__
    use_legacy_function=use_legacy_function)
  File "/Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3371, in __init__
    self._function = wrapper_fn.get_concrete_function()
  File "/Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2939, in get_concrete_function
    *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2906, in _get_concrete_function_garbage_collected
    graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3213, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3075, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "/Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 986, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3364, in wrapper_fn
    ret = _wrapper_helper(*args)
  File "/Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3299, in _wrapper_helper
    ret = autograph.tf_convert(func, ag_ctx)(*nested_args)
  File "/Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 258, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    testData.py:57 fetchData  *
        indices    = tf.range(start=sampleCount, limit=sampleCount+updates.shape[0], dtype=tf.int32)
    /Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:1074 _run_op
        return tensor_oper(a.value(), *args, **kwargs)
    /Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:1125 binary_op_wrapper
        return func(x, y, name=name)
    /Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:1443 _add_dispatch
        y = ops.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype_hint=x.dtype.base_dtype, name="y")
    /Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1499 convert_to_tensor
        ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
    /Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:338 _constant_tensor_conversion_function
        return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    /Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:264 constant
        allow_broadcast=True)
    /Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:282 _constant_impl
        allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
    /Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py:444 make_tensor_proto
        raise ValueError("None values not supported.")

    ValueError: None values not supported.
```

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def main( ):

    inputData      = np.zeros((1000, 3), dtype=np.float32)
    inputData[:,0] = np.sin(np.arange(1000)/360)
    inputData[:,1] = np.cos(np.arange(1000)/360)
    inputData[:,2] = np.sin(np.arange(1000)/360) * np.cos(np.arange(1000)/360) # Generate some input data
    inputData      = tf.convert_to_tensor(inputData, dtype=tf.float32)

    outputData     = np.random.randint(low=0, high=3, size=1000, dtype=np.int32) # Generate random output data

    eventData      = np.zeros((1000,2), dtype=np.int32)
    eventData[:,0] = np.arange(1000)                                                                  # Begin index of sparse sampling
    eventData[:,1] = np.arange(1000) + np.random.randint(low=80, high=121, size=1000, dtype=np.int32) # End   index of sparse sampling
    eventData      = tf.convert_to_tensor(eventData, dtype=tf.int32)

    totalSampleCount = int(1000)
    eventCount       = int(1000)
    inputDim         = int(300)
    outputDim        = int(3)
    batchSize        = int(256)
    epochCount       = int(5)
    stepsPerEpoch    = np.floor(666/batchSize)

    trainINDX      = np.arange(666)
    validationINDX = np.arange(666,1000)

    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=15, kernel_size=15, strides=1, padding='same', dilation_rate=1, activation='relu', use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros', input_shape=(inputDim,3)),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5, strides=None, padding='valid'),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', use_bias=True),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.50),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(outputDim, activation='softmax')
    ])

    model.compile( optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=True),
                   loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
                   metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])

    def fetchData(eventINDX, y): # This function picks up the requested elements from inputData

        sampleINDX = tf.zeros([inputDim], dtype=tf.int32) # Initialize sampleINDX to zero

        Ib = tf.gather_nd(eventData, [tf.cast(eventINDX, dtype=tf.int32), 0]) # Begin of sparse sampling
        Ie = tf.gather_nd(eventData, [tf.cast(eventINDX, dtype=tf.int32), 1]) # End   of sparse sampling

        indices    = tf.range(start=0, limit=24, dtype=tf.int32)
        updates    = tf.range(start=Ib-24, limit=Ib, dtype=tf.int32)
        sampleINDX = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(sampleINDX, tf.expand_dims(indices, axis=1), updates)

        sampleCount = tf.Variable(24, dtype=tf.int32)

        updates    = tf.range(start=Ib, limit=Ie, delta=5, dtype=tf.int32)
        indices    = tf.range(start=sampleCount, limit=sampleCount+updates.shape[0], dtype=tf.int32)
        sampleINDX = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(sampleINDX, tf.expand_dims(indices, axis=1), updates)

        sampleCount.assign_add(updates.shape[0])
           
        remainingSampleCount = tf.math.subtract(tf.constant(inputDim, dtype=tf.int32), sampleCount)

        indices    = tf.range(start=sampleCount, limit=inputDim, dtype=tf.int32)
        updates    = tf.range(start=Ie, limit=Ie+remainingSampleCount, dtype=tf.int32)
        sampleINDX = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(sampleINDX, tf.expand_dims(indices, axis=1), updates)

        X = tf.gather(inputData, tf.math.floormod(sampleINDX, totalSampleCount), axis=0)

        return X, y

    print('')
    for i in range(10):
        X, y = fetchData(i,outputData[i])
        print('trainINDX = %3d, X.shape = [ %3d, %d ]' % (i, X.shape[0], X.shape[1]))
    print('')

    trainData = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((trainINDX, outputData[trainINDX]))
    trainData = trainData.shuffle(buffer_size=trainINDX.size, reshuffle_each_iteration=True) 
    trainData = trainData.map(fetchData, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    trainData = trainData.repeat()
    trainData = trainData.batch(batchSize, drop_remainder=True)
    trainData = trainData.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

    validationData = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((validationINDX, outputData[validationINDX]))
    validationData = validationData.map(fetchData, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    validationData = validationData.batch(batchSize, drop_remainder=False)
    validationData = validationData.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

    history = model.fit(x=trainData, steps_per_epoch=stepsPerEpoch, validation_data=validationData, verbose=1, epochs=epochCount)

if __name__== "__main__":
  main( )
```

Any help fixing the described issue will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that replacing "updates.shape[0]" with "tf.shape(updates)[0]" solves that particular problem. However, this leads to another problem described below.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def main( ):

    inputData      = np.zeros((1000, 3), dtype=np.float32)
    inputData[:,0] = np.sin(np.arange(1000)/360)
    inputData[:,1] = np.cos(np.arange(1000)/360)
    inputData[:,2] = np.sin(np.arange(1000)/360) * np.cos(np.arange(1000)/360) # Generate some input data
    inputData      = tf.convert_to_tensor(inputData, dtype=tf.float32)

    outputData     = np.random.randint(low=0, high=3, size=1000, dtype=np.int32) # Generate random output data

    eventData      = np.zeros((1000,2), dtype=np.int32)
    eventData[:,0] = np.arange(1000)                                                                  # Begin index of sparse sampling
    eventData[:,1] = np.arange(1000) + np.random.randint(low=80, high=121, size=1000, dtype=np.int32) # End   index of sparse sampling
    eventData      = tf.convert_to_tensor(eventData, dtype=tf.int32)

    totalSampleCount = int(1000)
    eventCount       = int(1000)
    inputDim         = int(300)
    outputDim        = int(3)
    batchSize        = int(256)
    epochCount       = int(5)
    stepsPerEpoch    = int(np.floor(666/batchSize))

    trainINDX      = np.arange(666)
    validationINDX = np.arange(666,1000)

    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=15, kernel_size=15, strides=1, padding='same', dilation_rate=1, activation='relu', use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros', input_shape=(inputDim,3)),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5, strides=None, padding='valid'),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', use_bias=True),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.50),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(outputDim, activation='softmax')
    ])

    model.compile( optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=True),
                   loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
                   metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])

    def fetchData(eventINDX, y): # This function picks up the requested elements from inputData

        sampleINDX = tf.zeros([inputDim], dtype=tf.int32) # Initialize sampleINDX to zero

        Ib = tf.gather_nd(eventData, [tf.cast(eventINDX, dtype=tf.int32), 0]) # Begin of sparse sampling
        Ie = tf.gather_nd(eventData, [tf.cast(eventINDX, dtype=tf.int32), 1]) # End   of sparse sampling

        indices    = tf.range(start=0, limit=24, dtype=tf.int32)
        updates    = tf.range(start=Ib-24, limit=Ib, dtype=tf.int32)
        sampleINDX = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(sampleINDX, tf.expand_dims(indices, axis=1), updates)

        sampleCount = tf.Variable(24, dtype=tf.int32)

        updates    = tf.range(start=Ib, limit=Ie, delta=5, dtype=tf.int32)
        indices    = tf.range(start=sampleCount, limit=sampleCount+tf.shape(updates)[0], dtype=tf.int32)
        sampleINDX = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(sampleINDX, tf.expand_dims(indices, axis=1), updates)

        sampleCount.assign_add(tf.shape(updates)[0])
           
        remainingSampleCount = tf.math.subtract(tf.constant(inputDim, dtype=tf.int32), sampleCount)

        indices    = tf.range(start=sampleCount, limit=inputDim, dtype=tf.int32)
        updates    = tf.range(start=Ie, limit=Ie+remainingSampleCount, dtype=tf.int32)
        sampleINDX = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(sampleINDX, tf.expand_dims(indices, axis=1), updates)

        X = tf.gather(inputData, tf.math.floormod(sampleINDX, totalSampleCount), axis=0)

        return X, y

    print('')
    for i in range(10):
        X, y = fetchData(i,outputData[i])
        print('trainINDX = %3d, X.shape = [ %3d, %d ]' % (i, X.shape[0], X.shape[1]))
    print('')

    trainData = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((trainINDX, outputData[trainINDX]))
    trainData = trainData.shuffle(buffer_size=trainINDX.size, reshuffle_each_iteration=True) 
    trainData = trainData.map(fetchData, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    trainData = trainData.repeat()
    trainData = trainData.batch(batchSize, drop_remainder=True)
    trainData = trainData.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

    validationData = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((validationINDX, outputData[validationINDX]))
    validationData = validationData.map(fetchData, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    validationData = validationData.batch(batchSize, drop_remainder=False)
    validationData = validationData.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

    history = model.fit(x=trainData, steps_per_epoch=stepsPerEpoch, validation_data=validationData, verbose=1, epochs=epochCount)

if __name__== "__main__":
  main( )
```

Now the output of the attached file is

```
trainINDX =   0, X.shape = [ 300, 3 ]
trainINDX =   1, X.shape = [ 300, 3 ]
trainINDX =   2, X.shape = [ 300, 3 ]
trainINDX =   3, X.shape = [ 300, 3 ]
trainINDX =   4, X.shape = [ 300, 3 ]
trainINDX =   5, X.shape = [ 300, 3 ]
trainINDX =   6, X.shape = [ 300, 3 ]
trainINDX =   7, X.shape = [ 300, 3 ]
trainINDX =   8, X.shape = [ 300, 3 ]
trainINDX =   9, X.shape = [ 300, 3 ]

Epoch 1/5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testData.py", line 93, in <module>
    main( )
  File "testData.py", line 90, in main
    history = model.fit(x=trainData, steps_per_epoch=stepsPerEpoch, validation_data=validationData, verbose=1, epochs=epochCount)
  File "/Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1098, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
  File "/Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 840, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2829, in __call__
    return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1848, in _filtered_call
    cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
  File "/Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1924, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "/Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 550, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "/Users/relaxation82/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError:  Error while reading resource variable _AnonymousVar24 from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/_AnonymousVar24/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.
     [[{{node range_3/ReadVariableOp}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1569]

Function call stack:
train_function
```